# My flask app is all black and isn't inputting my variable in an h1 using jinja

Tags: python, html, flask

my flask app is all black and i don't know what to do here is my

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html", magic_word="alakazam")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Python app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>blah blah blah {{ magic_word }} </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to move your `index.html` file inside the `templates` directory. the directory structure should look like this:

```
/application.py
/templates
    /index.html
```

here are the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for rendering templates.